# Possible value(s) of $\frac{m_a+m_b+m_c}{a+b+c}$

Tags: geometry

Let $a,b,c$ be the side lengths and $m_a,m_b,m_c$ the lengths of their respective medians of an arbitrary triangle ABC.Then possible value(s) of $\frac{m_a+m_b+m_c}{a+b+c}$
$(A)\frac{4}{5}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{3}{2}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{6}{7}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{1}{2}$

---

This a multiple choice question.I do not know the relation between the side lengths and median lengths.How should i solve it?Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, $m_a^2=\frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4}$ and the medians of a triangle fulfill the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the first inequality listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_triangle_inequalities#Medians_and_centroid), the ratio $\frac{m_a+m_b+m_c}{a+b+c}$ is always between $\frac{3}{4}$ and $1$, hence the answer is given by $(A)+(C)$. Try to prove such fact by elementary means, it is not difficult if you know that
$$ m_a^2 = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-2a^2}{4} $$
holds by [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem). Also consider the following picture:
[image]

showing that the medians fulfill the triangle inequality, and that the ratio between the areas of $M_A M_B M_C$ and $ABC$, with $AB=c,AC=b,BC=a$, $M_A M_B = m_c, M_A M_C = m_b$, $M_B M_C = m_a$, is $\color{red}{\large\frac{3}{4}}$.